# Unix permission denied error even though directory is writable

Tags: unix, permissions

I am having trouble setting up permission for my directory. 
The directory in question is,

```
/usr/home/Test/me
```

I have set it to `777` using `chmod` command as can be seen here,

```
drwxrwxrwx  2 root  me  2 May 22 00:06 me
```

The permission of my `Test` directory are as follows,

```
drwxrwxrwt  4 root           wheel           4 May 22 00:06 Test
```

Now I am running the following code to check if directory is writeable,

```
if [ ! -d "$SDIR" -o ! -w "$SDIR" ]; then
  echo "ERROR: directory $SDIR not writable"
  exit 1
fi
```

and it always shows directory not writable. I don't understand why it always says not writable even though i set it to `777` ?

Comment: I works well for me. Something else is wrong...

Comment: Is there anyway to figure out whats wrong with it ?

Comment: Hard to help you without the environnement under the hands. Did you try with another dir?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what that "$SDIR" means, and I'm quite sure that is there the problem.

I run a similar script, passing the folder as parameter, and it works.

```
if [  -d $1 -a ! -w $1 ]; then
  echo "ERROR: directory $SDIR not writable"
  exit 1
else
  echo "It is a directory and it is writable"
fi
```

Comment: `$SDIR` is `/usr/home/Test/me`

Comment: In this case probably you should remove the double quotes: `if [ ! -d $SDIR -o ! -w $SDIR ]; then`